# pg_dump and pg_restore (DROP IF EXISTS)

Tags: postgresql

I want a completely shell-based solution for testing my database by allowing my to restore it to a consistent state by running a terminal command.

I dump my database like so:

```
pg_dump -F c -b -f -i -h domain.edu -p 5432 -n myschema -U me mydatabase -W -f mydump.sql
```

Then I want to restore it like so:

```
pg_restore -h domain.edu -p 5432 -U me -d mydatabase -W mydump.sql
```

but it doesn't work because I get tons of errors like these:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  constraint "settings_person_id_fkey" for relation "settings" already exists
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY settings
    ADD CONSTRAINT settings_learner_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES pe...
```

basically there are just a bunch of things that need to be dropped first before being re-added (`DROP TABLE <whatever> IF EXISTS`, same with types, etc).

How can I do this with Postgres? I don't want to use the `psql` console, only the linux terminal.

Comment: What is the difference between "console" and "linux terminal"? You want the `--clean` option for `pg_restore`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I think they meant the psql console. You are correct with the `--clean` switch.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @crazymykl, no that doesn't quite do it. I added the `--clean` flag, but when I insert rows after the dump and then use the dump to restore the database, those rows are still there. that's not the effect I want.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your script. `--clean` *drops* everything before importing the dump. Those rows can **not** be there.

Comment: correct, I was restoring to the wrong schema.

Comment: `--clean` - this option is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore. From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: `pg_dump -F c` ... is  the custom format so as has been pointed out `--clean(-c)` will only apply when you add it to the `pg_restore` command. To be clear the `c` after `-F` means custom not clean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to restore the database to a consistent state, I recommend you to drop and recreate it before restoring the dump:

```
dropdb -h domain.edu -U me mydatabase
createdb -h domain.edu -U me -T template0 mydatabase # adjust encoding/locale if necessary
pg_restore -h domain.edu -p 5432 -U me -d mydatabase -W mydump.sql
```

Comment: Note that the drop will fail when there are open connections to the database. While postgres 13 introduced an option to force a drop, that's not available in previous versions. See [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11893/196291) for details and work-arounds.

Answer (score 37):

You could use `--clean` in pg_dump to first drop objects:

```
pg_dump --clean
```

## Backup

```
pg_dump --clean -U user database > database.sql
```

## Restore

```
psql -U user -d database -f database.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, after all the trick is just to take dumps using `--clean` which makes it behave like mysql dumps :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `--clean --if-exists` when restoring the data without the need for having used any specific option when the backup was created.

You don't need to drop and recreate the whole database, nor does it require that `--clean` has been used in the backup.

```
pg_restore -h domain.edu -p 5432 -U me --clean --if-exists -d mydatabase -W mydump.sql
```

`--clean` makes pg_restore `drop` all objects first, and `--if-exists` prevents that non-existent objects cause a failure.

Note that `--if-exists` is not listed as a separate option in the [postgres docs for pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgrestore.html), but it is mentioned in the description of the `--clean` option:

> ```
> -c
> --clean
> ```
>
> Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (Unless
> --if-exists is used, this might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

Comment: [Tom Lane's docs proposal](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/998115.1695920626%40sss.pgh.pa.us) to make `pg_restore`'s `--clean` and `--if-exists` easier to understand.